# Bulk insert documents but if it exists only update provided fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6.8

I have an index which contains data as follows:

```json
{
  "some_field": string, -- exists in my database
  "some_other_field": string, -- exists in my database
  "another_field": string -- does NOT exist in my database
}
```

I have a script which grabs data from a database and performs a bulk insert. However, only some of the fields above come from the database as shown above.

If a document already exists, I still want to update the fields that come from the database, but without overwriting/deleting the field that does not come from the database.

I am using the `bulk` API to do this, however, I lose all data relating to `another_field` when running the script. Looking at `bulk` docs, I can't find any options to simply update an existing doc.

I am unable to share the script, but hope this might be enough information to shine some light on possible solutions.

Comment: @Paulo is right. You must provide the id to update an existing document if not this will create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR;

Yes it is use `index`, as [the doc explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-api-request-body):

> (Optional, string) Indexes the specified document. **If the document exists, replaces the document** and increments the version. The following line must contain the source data to be indexed.

But make sure to provide the `_id` of the document in case of an update.

## To understand

I created a toy project to replay and understand:

```json
# post a single document

POST /71177773/_doc
{
  "some_field": "data",
  "some_other_field": "data"
}

GET /71177773/_search

# try to "update" with out providing an id
POST /_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"71177773"}}
{"some_field":"data","some_other_field":"data","another_field":"data"}

# 2 Documents exist now
GET /71177773/_search 

# Try the same command but provide using the Id on the first documents
POST /_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"71177773", "_id": "<Id of the document>"}}
{"some_field":"data","some_other_field":"data","another_field":"data"}

# It seems it worked
GET /71177773/_search
```

If your question was:

> Is Elasticsearch smart enough to recognise I want to update an existing document without providing the Id ?

I am afraid it is not possible.